# Hierarchical Select reset when I click add another item

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom content type that has an unlimited field. This field is from field collection type and it contains a field that is from taxonomy type and with a hierarchical select widget. When I want add a node of that type and choose a value for hierarchical select field and then click add another item the value of the hierarchical select will reset. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily I fixed it by rearranging the hierarchical select field at top and add another item field(image field) at the bottom of that field.

You can rearrange the field under Mange Fields.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that I rearrange the field collection fields? I did it and change the order of fields in field collection and the taxonomy term field is the first field and there are 5 other fields next to that but when I click _add another item_ the selected value for the previous item's taxonomy term will remove.

Comment: @SaeedRajabi I done this without field collection, I think you have to submit a bug to hierarchical select issue queue.